# Downloading Blob from MySQL Database to its original format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download, blob

I'm trying create a website where you can upload a file and afterwards you can download it to your local computer. I'm doing this by storing the the file in a blob and also storing the size of the file and the mime type of the file as well, now this is working as expected.

What I want to do now is to download that blob of data and restore it to its original format. For example if I uploaded a *test.docx* file in the database I can download *test.docx* as it was before.

I am managing to make it download but the problem I'm having is that it's downloading the HTML in the page and the blob is a bin (A lot of symbols).

**Download.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download File From MySQL</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "root";
$dsn ='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=filerepository';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn,$dbUser,$dbPassword);

$query = "SELECT ID,Title FROM FoldersFiles";
foreach($dbh->query($query,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
?>
        <a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Title'];?></a> <br>
<?php
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $query2 = "SELECT Title,Format,Content,FileSize FROM  FoldersFiles WHERE ID = ?";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query2);
    $sth->execute(array($_GET['id']));
    $result =  $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $size = $row['FileSize'];
        $type = $row['Format'];
        $title  = $row['Title'];
        $content = $row['Content'];
    }
    require_once('/var/www/uploadFile/downloadFile.php');
    Download($size,$type,$title,$content);
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**downloadFile.php**

```
<?php
function Download($size,$type,$title,$content)
{

        header("Content-Length: $size");
        header("Content-Type: $type");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$title\"");

        echo $content;

}
```

I have split them because there was a similar problem where he fixed it by doing that but I still am having the problem.

I am using Ubuntu as my OS to develop this website, might this affect it? Also when I download the file it doesn't download in any format.

**Data being downloaded**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download File From MySQL</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
        <a href="download.php?id=46">Main</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=65">ICE</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=66">PHP</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=67">National Diploma Year 2</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=68">National Diploma Year 1</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=73">Semester 1</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=74">Object Orient Programing</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=75">Presentations</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=76">Homework</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=106">test</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=108">test</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=109">Main</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=111">File Repository</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=114">Documentation</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=115">Documentation</a> <br>
        <a href="download.php?id=125">test</a> <br>
PK\0\0\0\0\0!\02‘oWf\0\0¥\0\0\0[Content_Types].xml ¢( \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0´”ËjÃ0E÷…þƒÑ¶ØJº(¥ÄÉ¢ehúŠ4NDõB£¼þ¾ã81¥$14ÉÆ ÏÜ{Ï1ƒÑÚšl  µw%ë=–“^i7+Ù×ä-d&á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼½L60#µÃ’ÍS
Oœ£œƒXø\0Ž*•V$:ÆB~‹ðû^ïKï¸”§Úƒ
/P‰…IÙëš~7$²ì¹i¬³J&B0ZŠDu¾têOJ¾K(H¹íÁ¹xG
ŒL¨+Çvººš¨dcÓ»°ÔÅW>*®¼\\XR§mpúªÒZ}í¢—€HwnMÑV¬ÐnÏ”Ã-ì\")/ÒZwB`ÚÀË4¾Ýñ    ®°sîDXÁôój¿Ì;A*Êˆ©Ëc´Ö‰Ö\04ßþÙ[›S‘Ô9Ž> ­•ø±÷{£Vç4p€˜ôéW×&’õÙóA½’¨Ù|»d‡?\0\0\0ÿÿ\0PK\0\0\0\0\0!\0‘·ï\0\0\0N\0\0\0_rels/.rels ¢( \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0¬’ÁjÃ0@ïƒýƒÑ½QÚÁ£N/cÐÛÙ[ILÛØj×þý<ØØ]éaGËÒÓ“ÐzsœFuà”]ð–U
Š½  Öù^Ã[û¼x\0•…¼¥1xÖpâ›æöfýÊ#I)Êƒ‹YŠÏ‘øˆ˜ÍÀå*Döå§i\")ÏÔc$³£žqU×÷˜~3 ™1ÕÖjH[{ª=E¾†ºÎ~
f?±—3-ÂÞ²]ÄTê“¸2j)õ,l0/%œ‘b¬
ð¼Ñêz£¿§Å‰…,    ¡   ‰/û|f\\ZþçŠæ?6ï!Y´_áoœ]Aó\0\0ÿÿ\0PK\0\0\0\0\0!\0³¾‹\0\0¶\0\0\0word/_rels/document.xml.rels ¢( \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0¬“ÍjÃ0„ï…¾ƒØ{-;mC   ‘s)\\[÷d{ýCõc¤MZ¿}EJ‡ÓƒŽ3bg¾…Õzó­; ó½5²$†¦²uoZÅöá˜\'ij©¬A#zØä÷wë7T’ÂïúÁ³b¼€ŽhXqî«µô‰Ð„—Æ:-)H×òAVŸ²E¾HÓ%wÓÈ¯2Ù®àvõ#°bð?Ù¶iú
_mµ×hèF÷H6ó!SºIÀÉIBðÛ‹¨4*œõ\\}³Þìu‰.l|!8[sË˜fñp”¿f6Çð“¡±†
Yª  ÇÙšƒxŠ  ñ…åûŸ“œ˜\'~õÛò\0\0\0ÿÿ\0PK\0\0\0\0\0!\0K”¸ÄÅ0\0\0ž4\0\0\0\0word/document.xmlì}ëŽã¶¶æÿæ„š?`\'-RÔ­æ$gtMé=éN‚ó+PÙ¬²vÛ’¤êJå×~Œ3Àpžå<Ê~’!)Ë%«lëbÙ–å•½Ñ*S²Lr}ëÊÅÅù×?séMÒ0Ž¾½AßÈ7&ñ4Œ¾½ùõ“ÿµq#¥YMƒyÑoožizó¯ßý÷ÿö/O·Óxò¸ Q&±WDéíÓròíÍ,Ë–·oß¦“]é7‹p’Äi|Ÿ}3‰oãûûpBß>ÅÉô-–‘,þZ&ñ„¦)û=\'ˆ¾éÍêu‹×o‹—4b7ïãddìcòðv$Ÿ—_³·/ƒ,¼çaöÌÞ-kÅkâoo“èvõŠ¯×â_¹Í;´ºßHšünþw5âß&tÎúGé,\\¾£ëÛØÍYñ’/ûñe1/ž{Z\"r
Ü$xb——6éþ4ÿÒbž÷|ÿ‘Ü€\"üëo4éÂæo=YaôòÃ¦¦4¹Hm÷\\}Áòá0â|ŸÄË—·…‡½í]ôyý.ÎÙ-Þµ\"ryhéaù8–Œ“ÛwQœwsÖ#F2‰ÍºÄa}ó“8wñô™_—¬™Ü.ƒ$x7ýöF³LKÖ-óF´fôÏŒ·ê«ÿXë-“nÓ_¾½‘eOG²j­›>$¼ÑT0BÚºÑ¥÷Áã<{ýø‡R“èÅ‡„_Òe0a#`÷åoä_˜‡|N1Yøå‘)xÌâ›·ükŸ°_‚ù·7Æó4É[“ü‰GYÊ_™NBFçô!¦Ò¯ïøËhfVßÞ|
4•~¦OÒ/ñ\"ˆøÍ™¥•ç\'ié³ø‘ô¯â§1)Zþk¥¶·«¾¼]3Ù:k\'ëô]þ¯“Šë$žÇ¼C¢Ç²ø¯:6E{=¶¼­ÛÓ­Ð]‚‚Œ6Ë„¦4ùBo¾ói=²O4Ë¿OÅNôq”œ}Ñã\"ÿ#œ™¯\'$9»÷nZ´¡ÕÈ×_èˆ[>Bk>DBõ¯^~¤”?|B7@\0V¶ [´
Ý½Œ†cõ×å<¦Íqkn·À­?Eíë\0r¹@î‡$üÎéMß| éÓ[:
³¯šÃØŒ\0cæ%ŒªÃÄü·pÞÃ`0|~owæœxÁ©•Jq$e3*ÝÇó)MR)ˆ¦RÂlãéù\0v\0û,æ ¤y¸³€G9¼i0™I÷ß4†³ÍÉp8ŸÎ>³¡¥e/i’…Ì–¾çŸÓð/ÚÜ±`°<,\'ôKÈWUSéÍ$^2HKñ½ÄlI {µäš¶@7îÝ²G,Ïtº›£{»•ý>~xà¤Þ€siÌuà¼<&¾ge®²„    –¶0»”þ™T0s?Ìü+»J¿Ð‡0Írd7wmÀ`Åû)ˆ‚*’ªò°ôñ9Íè¢9œU€3Ày¨rZ`<}¼K\'I¸l)§94Ø\0ì³¯;Ñ ™Ì]›C—ƒô‚2ýNB.9}{\'Ùè’EÖœºhÃ\'¹o¾4n]†“L \"ˆ&³8Y£ÅÐtFÂ/·    e÷CÖúÇŸü\'þ‘ŒU¾àY¤ó†Ólv+ÿÏ
fÙ-úF]f7R|;K.ž×‰°¢)ÍØkV·ÅÌÕž‹a|{ó?™ÿ¿8‰?SöàýªŸ¼ƒDG!ˆ#‹>4É‘Ý®Ówù¿\'ÉÈæ‰‹ôöàÓZñjØ`ÝÚý¥cóHÚ$ˆ¤IBƒŒò”0‘â§Hzà›yšzðÙ®\0è«\0´W¤˜HOÌ “fÁZúk¦ÜB~KO3š°6*@ÜŸ†÷÷¬6XÄì2¥KñÍ¦<}e?I‹Gö~ö•eðÜf9eðY´ÀWÁ<\"—Jƒ}šÅ rXÇÍ9†g2,‘Îøƒ¬eÁX(›IK/ç´êw>z˜—†ÁÝ>ºq³ËG×é£Ÿ+Ñöš|t‡|tðÑ‹ÖCvMÝ×X{9ƒÏÖ,$+ØlC„vo6Û»{é9~\\YcÁjˆ0Ÿ&¾—B6\0žå•ïIïÖÛG¸Ç¿2•8¥ANØwž›ãÿùœ€À\'ŸEòE1‰ ó,aÏ%¸g¯§æ“ÿ%NKÍŸ¥GQe€1Ë„&YFy\"d^G
Ëû¬š{3ÎàS\"®Jäy5wÌC…¿Rüžˆx=ÐLŠâ,¼™ï™‚x–&³ z`Ýg_ 3¡2¸a¯Zo;œË%Z°Åà*-®‚-~PŸB7`¬±Þ-.±ùûcÊ0/-ã%S<ú   f™ÇL\'´@üàs.ñWø)]2<
```

Please tell me if you need any more information that might help you :D

Comment: Why are you storing the file as a blob in the database? That makes very little sense. Store the file as a file on your server then just store the file name in the database.

Comment: Will that make more sense when you want to deal with loads of files? And then is it possible for them to download it? Like what i am trying to do?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can either link directly to the file with your a tags, or if you don't want them to be able to see the direct link you can still link to download.php but have download.php open the file, read it and then output it as you are doing already.

Comment: okay to drawing board then! tough i was almost finished but if what you are is more effective(which it does sound like it) i will do it, Thank you for the tip

Comment: You shouldn't need to change much. All you need to do is instead of saving the data as blob, write the file to a location on your server then save the path in the database. Then modify the download script to load the location from the path and read the file.

Comment: Ye i am trying that but something is wrong it not letsing my upload a 200kb file while before it let me.

Answer (score 0):

that data seems ok; it's just the ascii/utf8 interpretation of some binary data
remember that you cannot send header() if there was already any other echo/print

so what you wanna do is to place that output **above** that html start tag end end it with a die();

Comment: Ye i do know that and i have output buffering turned on right now aswell.